# windows 7 home premium reinstallation problems

Tags: windows-7

My dell Studio 1749 is over 6 years old and has never given any problems.I need to reinstall windows becasue a few weeks ago after doing updates from windows it started telling me my copy of windows build 7601 was not genuine.So I took the machine in to be cleaned etc and using my oem installation disks (64bit) reinstalling windows.  Unfortunately the oem disks have become corrupted but I have the product key etc. Dell do not seem to be interested.  I live in Turkey and a friend downloaded another windows 7 on my computer but 32bit.  The video drivers seem to need updating and everything is slower than before.   As you can see I am useless at this sort of thing and because of my location there is the added language problem.

Can anyone come up with any ideas of how I can get my lovely machine back?

Answer (score -1):

You can get a copy of the Windows 7 x64 installation .iso-file at [Microsoft.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7)

This iso-file can be burned onto a dvd or loaded onto an usb-stick.
With this you should be able to install Windows 7 on your machine.

After this you need to install any drivers (like the gpu you mentioned). These drivers are available on the gpus manufacturers site.

Comment: The link you provided only allows people with a retail Windows 7 license to download it.  The Windows 7 license the author has would be an OEM license per their description.